# Сортировка мапы по убыванию частоты повторения слов

Tags: java, сортировка, map

Есть метод, который читает строки с файла, и выводит повторяющиеся слова и их количество. Нужно отсортировать по убыванию частоты повторения.

Пример:

```java
the 4

is 3

sunny 2

day 1
```

Код:

```java
public static void frequencyWordCounter(String url) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(url);
    
    InputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(file);
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
    
    String phrase = "";
    
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        phrase += scanner.nextLine();
    }
    
    inputFile.close();
    
    String[] words = phrase.toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
    
    String lowerCase = phrase.toLowerCase();
    
    Map<String, Integer> wordCountTable = new HashMap<>();
    
    int minWordLength = 0;
    for (String word : words) {
        String uniqueWord = word.toLowerCase();
        if (uniqueWord.length() > minWordLength) {
            if (wordCountTable.containsKey(uniqueWord)) {
                wordCountTable.replace(uniqueWord, wordCountTable.get(uniqueWord),
                wordCountTable.get(uniqueWord).intValue() + 1);
            } else {
                wordCountTable.put(uniqueWord, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    wordCountTable.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    });
}
```

Comment: добавьте сортировку где то тут `wordCountTable.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как можно оптимизировать (используя лямбда-выражения или stream API) код ниже изложенный, имея следующие условия задания?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1467859/); [Как отсортировать Map<Integer, Integer> по values?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1517910/); [сортировка по значению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1457715/); [Изменения кода при помощи lambda и Streams](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1347819/)

Answer (score 1):

Конкретно в данном случае для сортировки содержимого мапы слов по убыванию частот достаточно отсортировать поток (стрим) пар "ключ-значение", используя Stream API ([`Stream::sorted`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-)) и [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java8/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue-java.util.Comparator-):

```java
wordCountTable.entrySet().stream()  // Stream<Map.Entry<>>
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
    .forEach(entry -> {
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
    });
```

Если надо дополнительно отсортировать слова с одинаковыми частотами по алфавиту, это можно будет выполнить так:

```java
wordCountTable.entrySet().stream()  // Stream<Map.Entry<>>
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey)
    )
```

---

Также в представленном коде можно улучшить чтение данных и получение собственно мапы частот, по примеру реализации в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1467990/386633), добавив фильтр по длине слова и сортировку по убыванию:

```java
public void printWordFrequencies(String path, int minLength) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<String> input = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
        input
            .flatMap(str -> Arrays.stream(str.toLowerCase().split("\\P{L}+"))) // поток слов
            .filter(word -> word.length() >= minLength) // фильтр по длине
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                word -> word,
                Collectors.summingInt(word -> 1)
            )) // Map<String, Integer>
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
                Comparator.reverseOrder()
            ))
            .forEach(entry -> {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
            });
    }
}
```